# VMWare Lab Manager: What's the difference between Capture to Library and Archive to Library?

Tags: vmware-vcenter

On a configuration in my workspace I have two options, Capture to Library and Archive to Library. What's the difference between the two?

The Lab Manager User's Guide isn't very useful here:

> **Archive a Workspace Configuration to the Library**
>
> You can preserve the exact state of a configuration in the configuration library. Archived configurations are
> read‐only, but you can clone, export, and delete them.

Sounds like what Capture to Workspace does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have hands-on Lab Manager experience but this might be helpful:

http://communities.vmware.com/thread/277208

In addition to the poster's noted differences, the responder points out that if you archive and then clone, you can direct the clone to new datastore/storage while a capture resides in the datastore with the source.